# java data structure transformer(class "ProductKTORestResponse" to Map<String,?> or Map<String, Object>?)

Tags: java, spring, data-structures, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am new to Java, but not new to programming.
Right now I have a two class defined my service response structure. They looked like that: class and subclass, which will be my service response structure.

I am writing a gateway service, which will call other services. One service's response is "ktoconfigurableproduct", which is the same structure as "ProductKTORestResponse". What I need to do is add one more value "expire" to my "ProductKTORestResponse" response.

```
{
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ProductKTORestResponse extends BaseResponse implements RestMessage {

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> groupMetadata;

        private List<ProductKTOResponseParts> kits;

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> optionProductFacetAttributeMap;

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> optionValueMetadata;
   }

    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ProductKTOResponseParts {
        @NotEmpty
        private String partNumber;

        private Map<String, Collection<String>> groupKeyOptionValues;

        private Map<String, String> selectedOptions;

        private String type;

        private Map<String, List<String>> optionConstraints;
}
public class BaseResponse implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty(value = "expire")
    private Long expire;

}
```

Is there a way to transform "ProductKTORestResponse" to `Map<String,?>` or `Map<String, Object>`?
Thanks for any comments.

I tried to transform it directly. But I got

```
unchecked cast: 'com.apple.store.product.kto.domain.ktoconfigurableproduct' to 'java.util.map<java.lang.string,java.lang.object>'
```

Comment: `ProductKTORestResponse` contains three different `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` and a `List<ProductKTOResponseParts>` (in addition to any members which might be in `BaseResponse `. What would be in the `Map<String, Object>` resulting from a `ProductKTORestResponse` instance?

Comment: And please show the code you're trying to use to transform it -- I don't see `ktoconfigurableproduct` in the code you've shown.

Comment: If you're trying to cast an instance of `ProductKTOResponseParts` into a `Map` then it would fail, because your domain object is **not** a Map, it contains some Maps. You don't have to be a phone in order to use a phone. That said, it's not clear what advantage you're going to gain from combining all Maps contained within `ProductKTOResponseParts` into a `Map<String, Object>`? There's a little you can do with its values without type checking and cast, apart from printing.

Comment: BaseResponse only have one "private Long expire;"

Comment: "ktoconfigurableproduct" is the same as "ProductKTORestResponse".